# Help me identify a 1980s trilogy of books about a space faring rock band

Tags: story-identification, novel, soft-sci-fi

As a child in the 80s I had a book about a space faring rock band that I really loved the cover artwork for, and would love to see again. They travelled in a ship that had sails, which I think were powered by solar radiation or something similar.

I think it was part of a trilogy, but I may be wrong and more books may have been published in the series.

The band had four members who were all Caucasian teenagers, and I think one was female. They played strange looking instruments on one of the book covers. The cover I’m thinking of has an image of the space ship they flew in which was golden and looked like a yacht.

The title of the series may have been something like *Somebody and the Starjammers*. Something similar to *star jammers*.

The ship resembles the one used by Count Dooku in Star Wars. https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/b/b0/SolorSailer-DB.png/revision/latest?cb=20150819020309

The books were probably published around the mid 1980s, I also had a copy of Casca: The Warlord with a blue cover around the same time.

Comment: Is that "band" as in "a group of people" or as in "plays music"?

Comment: A band of musicians.

Comment: Are there any other details you can remember? If you loved the cover art, can you describe it? See [this checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) for hints on fleshing out the question.

Comment: A spacerock band? A trilogy? The Time of the Hawklords and I claim my five pounds! :-)

Comment: The Time of the Hawklords is not the one, sorry.

Comment: @QuintonHoffmann: I'm afraid that was a poor attempt at a joke. The Time of the Hawklords is legendary amongst Hawkwind fans for (a) featuring the band and (b) being almost unreadable.

Comment: More details. The band had four members who were all Caucasian teenagers, and I think one was female. They played strange looking instruments on one of the book covers. The cover I’m thinking of has an image of the space ship they flew in which was golden and looked  like a yacht.

Comment: The title of the series may have been something like “Somebody and the ‘starjammers’. Something similar to star jammers.

Comment: Out of interest, this was the image I was thinking of, though I did remember it in colour. 

https://img.bidorbuy.co.za/image/upload/user_images/987/1200987/1200987_150210150646_IMG_9212.JPG

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

[Brian Earnshaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Earnshaw)'s [*Star Jam Pack*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?20213) series features an interstellar rock band:

1. [*Starclipper and the Song Wars*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?261157) (1985)
2. [*Starclipper on the Snowstone*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?307140) (1986)
3. [*Starclipper and the Galactic Final*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?307139) (1987)